# Chinese fonts not being rendered correctly

Tags: css

I am trying to render chinese fonts as follows.
I put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
```

in the head of the index.php document.
In css/mystyle.css, I put this:

```
body {font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", "KaiTi", "楷体", STKaiti, 华文楷体", serif;    }
```

Then I wrote something in Chinese in the body of index.php.
The chinese text is displayed but not in the KaiTi font.

Does someone know where the problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your system have those fonts installed?

Comment: Hello Rob, how can I check that?

Comment: Have you tried `!important` in your CSS? `body { font-family: "KaiTi" !important; }`. Also, I don't have KaiTi installed on my machine, but if your site is online, I suggest to provide a link.

Comment: That font was not installed in my machine. That is why. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

If Georgia or Times New Roman are available on the user's system, it will load those fonts first, thus you will not see the Chinese font. You can create a CSS class that will call just that font, and apply that class to any elements where you want to use Chinese.

```
.chinese {
  font-family: "KaiTi";
}
<div class="chinese">你好</div>
```

Comment: Hello Adam, I do get chinese characters. But not in KaiTi font. The browser is not using Georgia nor Times New Roman since they cannot render Chinese. Your method did not work for me either. I guess, that Rob pointed it right. I do not have that font installed.